# Performing subtraction in SQL/finding the balance

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subtraction

SQL table here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/abe1da/9

Current Table:

| Year | Month | Type | Accounts | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 1 | Actual | abc | 20 |
| 2021 | 1 | Actual | def | 30 |
| 2021 | 1 | Actual | ghi | 40 |
| 2021 | 1 | Actual | X | 7 |
| 2021 | 1 | Actual | Y | 3 |
| 2021 | 1 | Actual | final | 105 |

Expected

| Year | Month | Type | Accounts | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 1 | Actual | abc | 20 |
| 2021 | 1 | Actual | def | 30 |
| 2021 | 1 | Actual | ghi | 40 |
| 2021 | 1 | Actual | X | 7 |
| 2021 | 1 | Actual | Y | 3 |
| 2021 | 1 | Actual | final | 105 |
| 2021 | 1 | Actual | BALANCE | 5 |

**SQL Attempt**

```
select year, month, type,
case when accounts in ('abc') then 'abc'
 when accounts in ('def') then 'def'
 when accounts in ('ghi') then 'ghi'
 when accounts in ('X') then 'x'
 when accounts in ('Y') then 'Y'
 when accounts in ('final') then 'final'
else 'balance'
end as account_2
,
sum
(
(case when accounts in ('abc','def','ghi','final','x','y') then amount
else 
(
(case when accounts in ('final') then (amount))-
(case when accounts in ('abc','def','ghi','x','y') then -amount else 0))
)
from new
```

Note: That balance of 5 represents thousands of small accounts which currently do not form part of a database.

Comment: You're ignored the last answer you were given? Your case expressions aren't complete, missing ends, and you aren't grouping by anything? Start with a single, simple expression and build it up... And you duplicate final in 2 case expressions.

Comment: This is normally the sort of thing you do in your front end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly:

```
select Year, Month, Type, Accounts, Amount
from new
union all
select year, month, type, 'balance',
       (sum(case when accounts = 'final' then amount else 0 end) -
        sum(case when accounts <> 'final' then amount else 0 end) 
       )
from new
group by year, month, type;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/abe1da/15) is a db<>fiddle.